# UICollectionViewCell Design

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am new in Swift and I am sitting with a project that I am trying to make the cells look like the design that I have. I have tried a lot of things but I can´t figure out how to make it work. I really appreciate all help that I can get.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48jop.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/?s=uicollectionview&cof=FORID%3A10). There are a lot of UICollectionView tutorials and how to customize its looks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom cells for your collection view. If you do not know how then click [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2)

You have to embed your `UILabel` into a `UIView` and add that `UIView` to custom collection view cell's `contentView`. Then you can do the following:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
view.layer.borderWidth = 1
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red
etc etc....
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay, do you know how to set it up to be like 1 cell row and then 3 cells per row and then 2 cells per row depending on the label width?

Comment: You have to write some logic to adjust the width of cells in `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath`. Unfortunately there is no method to set the number of items per row. There is a method where you can set the number of rows in section but that won’t help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. I'm using UICollectionViewLayout (sizeForItemAtIndexPath) to set the cell width depending on the text width. It seems to work. :-)